# Estimating the divergence of a "convex series."

Tags: sequences-and-series

An exercise from R.C. Buck's *Advanced Calculus*:

Let $f≥0$, $f'≥0$, $f'' \geq 0$ for $1≤x<\infty$. Show that

$$0≤ \sum_1^n f(k) - \int_1^n  f(x)dx - \frac12f(n) - \frac12f(1)≤\frac14f'(n)$$ for $n≥1$.

The general idea is to use the trapezoid and midpoint rules to estimate the integral and series in $[n, n+1]$. I don't see where the derivative bound comes in, some sort of mean value estimate?

Comment: did you try drawing it?

Comment: A quick picture tells me the trapezoid rule overestimates the integral, while the midpoint rule underestimates it. We can expand this to get $$\frac12(n+1-n)(f(n+1)+f(n))≥\int_{n}^{n+1}f≥\frac12(n+1-n)f(\frac{n+1+n}{2})$$ and summing from 1 to $n$ it is easy to get the left equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating by parts over $[k,k+1]$,

$$\int_k^{k+1} (x - k - 1/2)f'(x)\,dx= \frac1{2}f(k+1)+\frac1{2}f(k) -\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,dx.$$

Now integrate the LHS by parts again to get

$$ \frac1{2}f(k+1)+\frac1{2}f(k) -\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,dx \\= \frac1{8}f'(k+1) -\frac1{8}f'(k) - \frac1{2} \int_k^{k+1}(x - k -1/2)^2f''(x)\,dx \\\leqslant \frac1{8}f'(k+1) -\frac1{8}f'(k).$$

Sum over $k = 1, \ldots , n-1$ to obtain your right-side inequality:

$$\frac1{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f(k+1)+f(k)] - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,dx \leqslant \frac1{8}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f'(k+1)-f'(k)],\\ \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) -\frac1{2}f(n) - \frac1{2}f(1)- \int_1^nf(x)\,dx \leqslant \frac1{8}f'(n) - \frac1{8}f'(1) \leqslant \frac1{4}f'(n).$$

The final inequality follows from convexity and $f'(n) \geqslant f'(1) \geqslant 0$.

Comment: Thank you, very clever! Is there any trick to choosing (x-k-1/2)? Or is this just simply a case of reverse engineering the result to further manipulate the problem?

Comment: That is the deviation of $x$ from the mid-point -- so there is a geometric interpretation - which escapes me at the moment. But I know this method as the first step in the derivation of Euler Maclaurin summation.

Comment: The inequality works out in this case, because $f$ is convex --and $f'(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: The RHS of the first equality you give is the error in the trapezoidal approximation to the integral, so it makes sense to use this as a bound. $(x-k-\frac12)f'(x)$ is almost the equation of the tangent to $f$ at the midpoint (or perhaps the secant line since they have the same slope?). I'd be interested to determine more about the derivation of this error estimate.

Comment: @dnk_js91: You're welcome.  As you say, the LHS integral is the exact error. I wanted to manipulate this in a way that involved the difference of first derivatives -- so the telescoping sum would reduce to $f'(n)/4$. In this case I get $f'(n)/8 - f'(1)/8$ which happens to be less than $f'(n)/4$.  Maybe the less tight bound can be obtained another way.